# Como encontrar, verificar e alterar ficheiro?

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou com uma duvida visto ser novo a mexer no python. 
Eu tenho um ficheiro por exemplo:

```
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla 5
bla bla bla 846:545
energia 3
```

Eu pretendo ler do ficheiro `teste.txt` a informação energia.
Do qual quero verificar o numero que está, e.g o número 3, e se for preciso altera lo para o número 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que ler linha a linha e depois reescrever o arquivo:

```
arquivo = open("teste.txt","r")
linhas = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()
linhas_a_escrever = ''
for linha in linhas:
    if "energia" in linha:
       lixo,valor_energia = linha.split(" ")
       if int(valor_energia) == 3:
           linhas_a_escrever += "energia 5\n"
           continue
    linhas_a_escrever += linha
arquivo = open("teste.txt","w")
arquivo.write(linhas_a_escrever)
arquivo.close()
```

Imagino que isso seja o que você deseja fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era precisamente isto que pretendia, estava com dificuldades em conseguir validar e voltar a escrever de novo no ficheiro. já reparei no meu erro graças a voçes.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução criando um novo arquivo com o valor alterado:

```
novo = open('novo_ficheiro.txt', 'w')

with open('ficheiro.txt', 'r') as ficheiro:
    for linha in ficheiro:
        nova_linha = linha
        if 'energia' in linha:
            nova_linha = 'energia %i' % 4
        novo.write(nova_linha)
novo.close()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela vossa disponibilidade. A sua resposta esta correcta apenas preferi a versão do Felipe Avelar.